# WP emulator theme change

Tags: windows-phone-7

Everytime WP emulator starts,it has dark theme with red color. I prefer it to have light theme  and lime color.

Is there any way i can make those changes permanent so that next time emulator starts, it picks up what settings i want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly there is no way to make it persist settings.

However, you should use the dark theme as default, and then test with the white theme from time to time, since that best represents the consumers.